# Should we keep User Registration and User Update forms separate

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I have a user registration form and a user information update form. All the fields in both the forms are the same. So should I use the same registration form as User update form, on which all the information is fetched from database and is displayed on in the relevant fields. Please suggest me a solution. By the way I am doing all this stuff in Codeigniter.

Comment: Did you try to do something? What answer you want? Because, yes, you can use the same form. I don't see any problem with that. Really don't understand your problem here.

Comment: At first I designed two separate forms for registration and update. But the fields in both the forms were the same. So I decided to use just a single form for both the operations. But I was not sure will it work or not. I just checked some conditions on my view page and everything is working fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's probably not such a good idea, as a user registration form is usually available publicly, but a user update form should be behind a secured area / firewall and you should set up access control for who should be allowed to update a user (eg. only the user themselves and admins). 
But if you write your code in such a way that the forms can be reused in different context, then you could use the same code for both pages.

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Comment: In my system both the registration and updating user are done by Admin. So I think using only one form will be a good idea.

Comment: Yes I got my answer. Just used one form and saved a lot of coding effort. Thanks.